# How to remove 1 inch paddings without using \hoffset and \voffset?

Tags: margins, paper-size

I usually do the following to remove 1 inch padding.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\paperwidth=72.27pt
\paperheight=72.27pt
\voffset=-72.27pt
\hoffset=-72.27pt
\parindent=0sp
\special{papersize=\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(\paperwidth,\paperheight)
\psframe[linecolor=red](\paperwidth,\paperheight)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

How to remove 1 inch paddings without using \hoffset and \voffset?

Comment: I will tidy up the question above after migrating Herbert's answer.

Comment: The answer is already in Herbert's and mine answers to the other question. Use geometry and be happy: why reinvent the wheel? :) Performance time in loading **geometry**?

Comment: @egreg: For creating a single graphics, I don't need geometry.sty. I want to take a full control. :-)

Comment: @egreg: If I used geometry.sty, I will not know whether or not there are rounding errors in the author's calculation.

Comment: @xport: If you are that worried about having ultimate control, then LaTeX is a bad choice: use plain TeX and define only what you want.

Comment: @Joseph: Yes. I have a plan to migrate to plain TeX but the learning curve is so steep. I need a crash course focusing on branching, looping, arithmetic operation on number, counter, length.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sets the left and top margin to 0pt

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\oddsidemargin=-1in
\topmargin=-1in
\headheight=0pt
\headsep=0pt
\parindent=0pt
\usepackage{layout}
\begin{document}

\rule{\textwidth}{\textheight}

\layout

\end{document}
```

Comment: I prefer using `72.27` to get the exact value. :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
\oddsidemargin=-1in
\headsep=0pt
\headheight=0pt
\topmargin=-1in
\pagestyle{empty}
```

Comment: I prefer using `72.27pt` because using `1in` causes rounding error.

Comment: There's a difference of 1sp. About 5nm.